# Who is being parodied by Onizuka?

Tags: great-teacher-onizuka

In episode 8 of Great Teacher Onizuka, who is this "Kenshiro" that Onizuka is parodying?

[image: Onizuka is Kenshiro?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Onizuka is making a reference to Kenshiro from "[Fist of the North Star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fist_of_the_North_Star)".
In the English translation of the manga, this was added as a note.

Kenshiro's fiancée is called [Yuria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fist_of_the_North_Star_characters#Yuria).